# SQLite database in combination with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I'm changing my application from Activity's to Fragments, it's going great but I've one bug that won't let me open my database. Here's the error (from the logcat):

```
05-17 15:28:38.704  13025-13025/com.MJV.werktijden             E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
    at com.MJV.werktijden.DBAdapter.open(DBAdapter.java:71)
    at com.MJV.werktijden.OverviewFragment.onActivityCreated(OverviewFragment.java:38)
    at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1703)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried to solve it myself, but I couldn't find the problem. Just because this database did work when I used it with Activity's.
I'm opening the database with this method:

```
    //---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

And that method is being called from my Fragment:

```
private final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(getActivity());

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview_layout, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    db.open();
```

Thanks for helping in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### The Fix

Replace this line

```
private final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
```

with this

```
private DBAdapter db;
```

In the `onActivityCreated()` method, add the following line

```
db = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
```

### What is happening

In the line `private final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(getActivity());` in your `Fragment`, you are calling `getActivity()` before the activity is created. So, when the `SQLiteOpenHelper` tries to use the `Context` (your activity), it finds that it is null.

The simple fix is to call `getActivity()`(and thereby open your database) only after the `Activity` has been created. `onActivityCreated()` method is invoked after `Activity` has been created and hence the new code will be able to get the reference of your`Activity` via `getActivity()` without throwing any null exception.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any pending connections, it normally occurs when database is open in the given `Context`.

Check it if any unclosed connection is present in this `Fragment`.

Comment: This is just when I start the fragment, so there are no open connections. The first time it gets to the db.open() method is crashes and gives the logcat as I showed.